# Dominar 400 2022 engine coolant level is little over max

Tags: motorcycle, coolant, dominar

I bought a new Dominar 400 2022. When I went for the first service, I observed that my coolant level was almost touching min. So I asked the service engineer to top that up. When he topped up, he put the coolant little too much and now the coolant level is little over max level. And when engine heat up I can see the chamber is entirely full, because of coolant expansion. Is this a problem? Will having too much coolant damage my engine or any part of the bike?

I saw lots of threads about coolant level being min for dominar 400. But could not find anything related to my issue.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will damage it, but would think it probably could. Too much fluid could cause it to become over pressurized, which could blow out seals, gaskets, or hoses.

The easy thing to do is to remove some of the coolant out of it. You could easily use a turkey baster to do this for you (where I'm at, these are very cheap to purchase). Suck some out and put it in a clean container (in case you take too much out). Then fire up the engine and get it to temperature, noting the coolant level. Adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain the coolant level between min and max markings. As your engine heats up, the coolant volume will expand and if it's much above the max marking, it may overflow. I can not say if it will affect the powertrain but the coolant overflow will definitely ruin the plastic parts around if it occurs too often.